How can I update item stored in app state variable list
I am working on a notebook app that stores notes in an app state variable. I want the user to be able to update the content of the already existing note stored in the app state variable. The major problem I am encountering is not being able to find that existing index of the item since it is in a list. How do I go about this
I have tried the following steps; Update app state> update item at index> update field(Title)> item index in list?.... The last part is where I am having issues

Share your code that you have tried.

It will be easier to give you the answer if you attach your code

int index = notes.indexWhere((item) => item["id"] == selectedItemId);

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
